# Indexing and searching CSV table

Tags: java, csv

I am reading medium sized CSV files (up to 100K rows and 50 columns), and currently storing as 

`headers: List<String>
data: List<List<String>>`

I'd like to search this by cell values in a given column, returning `{irow, jcol}` . I have looked at guava `HashBasedTable` but this doesn't have a concept of numeric row index. Before writing my own (based on hastable indexing), I would be grateful to know of lightweight Open Source Java table tools that work with CSV structure.

NOTE: in response to @Basil I can work with a read-only solution but would probably use add/delete if it existed.

Comment: Why don't you create an additional hash map for your index pointing to the same row as in your `List<List<String>>`?  Then you have both the numeric row index and the column based index but no duplicates for the row data.

Comment: @vanje this is what I am doing - it's not robust against addition/deletion of data

Comment: @peter.murray.rust You didn't mention addition/deletion of data in your Question. That is a crucial criteria for a solution, in contrast to a read-only situation. Edit your Question with this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## H2 Database Engine

Why not use a relational database rather than twist your tabular data into non-tabular Java structures?

The [H2 Database Engine](http://h2database.com/) is written in pure Java. It can be embedded in your Java app.

H2 can directly read in CSV files. See [this tutorial](http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#csv) on using `CSVREAD` and `CSVWRITE`. Or use the Apache Commons CSV library to read in the CSV files.

Add an extra column for an incrementing integer number if you want the rows to have a sequential number, apparently what you mean by "row index".

You can specify the database be kept in memory rather than persisted to storage if you want to maximize performance.

## Concurrency

Your comment mentions this is a read-write situation with addition/deletion of data. That raises possible concurrency issues around multiple threads updating data structures in memory and synching file writes to storage.

That makes a database solution even more appropriate as [concurrency](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)) is a very tricky complicated problem already handled well by a database.

Be sure to understand your database’s concurrency strategy. There is no magic perfect solution to concurrency handling, trade-offs are always required. The H2 database by default  uses [MVCC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) as [its strategy](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#mvcc).

Comment: Accepting this as it seems a potentially useful approach , though it is more heavyweight that I would like.
Yes, row index is a sequential index number.